# I'm trying to create a tcp socket in one .c file and listen to it on another .c file. The connection attempt is failing

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

So I've created a .c file which acts as a coordinator server. This accepts a clients request and forks out a process to execute a .c file that acts as the server that directly tends to the clients request.

The coordinator listens on a udp port and receives the clients request. When it gets the request, it creates a tcp socket. It then forks a process which uses the execv() command to run the .c file of the other server. The socket is passed as a parameter. The .c file that has been executed by the child process will then use this socket, listen on it and attempt to accept the connection from the client.

The client meanwhile, has received the port number of the tcp socket created by the coordinator and is attempting to connect to the new server.

The issue is that the client fails when it reaches the connect() function. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

This is the code snippet in the coordinator where I fork out to execute the other server:

```
    int new_tcp_sock = setup_TCP();

    char cmd[5];

    sprintf(cmd, "%d", new_tcp_sock);

    char *argv[] = {cmd, NULL};

    if( (pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", getpid());
        execv("./chat_server", argv);
    }
```

The setup_TCP() function merely creates the socket:

```
int setup_TCP()
{
    printf("Session Server: Setting up server.\n");

    int b, s;
    struct sockaddr_in s1;

    bzero((char *)&s1,sizeof(s1));

    s1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    s1.sin_port = htons(5024);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (s < 0)
    {
        printf("Session Server: Error creating socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Session Server: Reached after socket.\n");

    b = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &s1, sizeof(s1));

    if(b < 0)
    {
        printf("Session Server: Error binding socket. Attempting to bind to alternate port.\n");
        s1.sin_port = htons(0);
        if(bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&s1, sizeof(s1)) < 0)
        {
            printf("Session Server: Error. Cannot bind.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            int socklen = sizeof(s1);

            if(getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr*)&s1, &socklen) < 0)
            {
                printf("Session Server: Bind successful. Unable to get alternate port number.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Session Server: New server port number: %d\n", ntohs(s1.sin_port));
        }
    }

    printf("Session Server: After binding.\n");

    tcp_port = ntohs(s1.sin_port);
}
```

In the .c file of the new server to be setup, I have the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    char *host = "localhost";
    char *port_number = "5004";
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    socklen_t server_addr_len;

    if( (sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
            printf("Session server: Error creating socket.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    server_addr = setup_UDP(host, port_number);
    server_addr_len = sizeof(server_addr);

    char buf[80];
    int a = tcp_listen(atoi(argv[1]));

    while(1)
    {
        read(a, buf, sizeof(buf)+1);
        write(a, buf, strlen(buf)+1);
    }
}

int tcp_listen(int socket)
{
    int l;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);

    if( (l = listen(socket, 20)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error. Cannot listen.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Listening\n");

    int csock = accept(socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);

    if(csock < 0)
        printf("Error accepting request.\n");
    else
        printf("Accepted\n");
    int csock = 0;

    return csock;
}
```

And finally, in the client, I firstly have this while loop to help communicate with coordinator and an inner while loop to talk to the other server:

```
while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin))
    {
        if(strncmp(buf, "Start", 5) == 0 || strncmp(buf, "Find", 4) == 0)
        {
            w = sendto(sock, buf, strlen(buf) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, server_addr_len);

            if( (r = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, &server_addr_len)) < 0 )
            {
                printf("Error reading back from server.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Got: %s\n", buf);
                int sock = chat_connect_function("127.0.0.1", buf);
                while( fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) )
                {
                    write(sock, buf, strlen(buf)+1);
                    read(sock, buf, sizeof(buf)+1);
                }
            }
            fputs(buf, stdout);
        }
        else if(strncmp(buf, "Exit", 4) == 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid start of statement. Could not recognize command\n");
        }
    }
```

The chat_connect_function() in the while loop is supposed to connect to the tcp socket which should be accepted by the new server:

```
int chat_connect_function(char *host, char *port_number)
{
    int s;
    struct hostent *host_info;
    struct sockaddr_in s1;

    bzero((char *)&s1,sizeof(s1));

    s1.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if ((s1.sin_port=htons((unsigned short)atoi(port_number))) == 0)
    {
        printf("TCP: Problem with port number.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if( host_info = gethostbyname(host) )
    {
        memcpy(&s1.sin_addr, host_info->h_addr, host_info->h_length);
    }
    else if ( (s1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host)) == INADDR_NONE )
    {
                printf("TCP: Error. Can't get host entry of %s.\n", host);
                exit(1);
        }

        if( (s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        {
            printf("TCP: Error creating socket.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&s1, sizeof(s1)) < 0)
        {
            printf("TCP: Error connecting to server.\n");
        }
        else
            printf("TCP: Connected to %s.\n", host);

        return s;
}
```

I apologize if I've posted too much code, but I'm at my wits end and can't figure out why the client prints "TCP: Error connecting to server.\n". 
Also, when I move the 'listen()' function from the code of the new server into the code of the coordinator, the client reports that the connection has been established.

Comment: "*... why the client prints 'TCP: Error connecting to server'.*" because the call to `connect()` failed. To get enlightened why a system call failed always log the value of `errno` and propably also what `strerror(errno)` tells you.

Comment: Perhaps use also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to debug (or understand what syscalls other applications are doing)

Comment: My guess would be that the client is calling `connect()` before the server has called `listen()` and `accept()`, so the connection fails with an `ECONNREFUSED` error.  You should call `listen()` inside of `setup_TCP()` so that the socket's listening port is actually listening and its backlog is available, before then sending the host/port to the client. Then `accept()` can retrieve the connection from the backlog. you might also want to think about lowering the backlog, since you are not going to have more than 1 client connecting to the listening socket, so a backlog of 20 is overkill.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look into it. @Alk, I've tried the strerror(errno) instinctively, but it returns 'unknown error' with a return value of -1.